# Django update monthly_score of each user with total likes for all their posts

Tags: python, sql, django, database

I want to update the `monthly_score` field for every user's `Profile`.

I have a `Post` model with a method to return the post's likes called `like_count`.

How do I use:

```
Profile.objects.update(monthly_score=Subquery())
```

to get the user's posts this month and return a sum of all their likes?

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
Profile.objects.update(
    monthly_score = Subquery(
        Post.objects.filter(
            user = Profile.user,
            date_posted__month = today.month
        ).aggregate(Sum(like_count))
    )
)
```

Comment: why did it not work? did you get an error? if so what was the error/traceback?

Comment: The error right now is in the part "user=Profile.user" returning TypeError at /leaderboard/
Field 'id' expected a number but got <django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.ForwardOneToOneDescriptor object at 0x03B64B38>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about [List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)? 
Something like this:

```
[Profile.objects.filter(pk = profile_item.pk).update(
    monthly_score = sum(
        [post_item.like_count() for post_item in Post.objects.filter(
            user = profile_item.user, 
            date_posted__month = today.month
        )]
    )
) for profile_item in Profile.objects.all()]
```

P.s.: fixed the error that @AlphaDjango wrote in comments.

Comment: Thank, you this is what I was looking for. However when I run the code I get an error of `'Profile' object has no attribute 'update'` . Do I need to add an update method to `Profile` or is there another way to fix this? Thanks

Comment: I did some searching and update on works on querysets and I believe profile_item is just the single object so I can't use update on it. Is there another way?